# restful resource providing html to mobile app

Tags: java, html, rest, jersey, templating

We currently handle the communication to/for backend api* and mobile (ios & android) apps.

For a stupid banner-like thingie, we should provide these apps with some HTML they'll render.

This is how it's done now:

```
String html ="<html>.....{somePlaceHolder}...</html>";
html = html.replace("{somePlaceHolder}", "We're good");
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
gson.toJson(html);
```

This looks pretty bad to me. Wrapping html inside json is pretty useless.
I'm sure some templating engine can help us out here.

I was wondering what's the best way to do it.
I suppose I could have some HTML files that I could load up and then have my rest resource produce **application/xhtml+xml** or **text/html** this one time instead of json.

Anybody has suggestion on some best practices.

Thanks

*we use jax-rs/jersey

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the whole problem correctly, but why do you want your RESTful service to return HTML in the first place.

I suppose the RESTful service should return JSON (or XML, for that matter) but the main point is, it should return only the actual data; no HTML at all, especially not HTML wrapped into JSON.

The application that calls the RESTful service should be responsible for the displaying of the data, that is wrapping the data into HTML.